# Spring rest docs can not generate generated-snippets using mvn clean package

Tags: spring-restdocs

I want to generate API docs using Spring rest docs. But it can not generate generated-snippets directory.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                            <attributes>
                                <snippets>${project.build.directory}\generated-snippets</snippets>
                            </attributes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                    </directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

UT file

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir = "target/generated-snippets")
public class LoginControllerTest {
    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation();

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                 .andDo(document("{ClassName}/{methodName}"))
        ;
    }
}
```

After I execute "mvn clean package", it cannot generate html file correctly due to " asciidoctor: ERROR: benyuan.adoc: line 12: include file not found: C:/{directory}/target/generated-snippets/LoginControllerTest/contextLoads/request-body.adoc
"

And the target directory is as below

```
classes/  generated-docs/  generated-sources/  generated-test-sources/  maven-archiver/  maven-status/  test-classes/
```

The "generated-snippets" is missing.

But when I just run the test file, it is ok.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Surefire executing any tests when you run `mvn clean package`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running your UT class LoginControllerTest not main Spring test class, By going to your class Right-click and click Run 'LoginControllerTest'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might occur when you are using Spring Boot >= 2.4, but your tests still run on JUnit 4. You either need to update your JUnit Dependency to Version 5 (and migrate your tests) or you can add the following to your dependencies:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
```

If this is your problem, then your test run most likely will also have only run 1 test